# Formatting Phone number in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

How might I format a phone number into (###) ###-#### using SQL in MS Access?

Here's what I have so far:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Value = Left(Value, 3) + Mid(Value, 3) + "-"
WHERE Field = "Phone"
```

Result:

Before running update query: (123) 9871234

After running update query:  (123 ) 9871234-

Comment: And what is the issue you are facing? Does your code produce the wrong thing? Is there an error?

Comment: And what is the result of your code?  Look like you just need to add a right(value, 4) and you are just about there

Comment: Read online help for `Mid()`.

Comment: You're trying to change the phone number by adding the last four digits on twice?  `(123) 9871234` > `(123 ) 9871234-1234`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook , Adding on the last four digits wasn't the intention. I figured I had to put it there to capture the last of them. I corrected my code so it doesn't add the last four again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the brackets and space:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Value],'(',''),')',''),' ','')
```

Then format as required:

```
FORMAT(VALUE,"(###) ###-####")
```

As an SQL statement:

```
SELECT FORMAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Value],'(',''),')',''),' ',''),"(###) ###-####")
FROM Table
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much! I have another question however-
Would using Left() and Mid() not have worked for the format that I was attempting to use? And if so, why not?

Comment: I can't check exact syntax at the moment, but yes your method could work. It would be something like `LEFT(Value,8) & '-' & MID(Value,9,LEN(Value))`. Use `&` instead of `+` to avoid adding numbers. The `8` includes brackets & spaces in the original value. You'll run into problems if the value is less than 9 characters with that method as well. Test the `FORMAT` with different length numbers as well - I'm not sure of the result.

Comment: Might also be worth looking at [input masks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/control-data-entry-formats-with-input-masks-e125997a-7791-49e5-8672-4a47832de8da).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for all the help!